# How to sync EFS to local storage(EBS)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-efs

We have a folder containing parquet files mounted on EFS so that multiple instances can access that folder to read/write. Everything was working fine but recently we found that the query that we ran on the parquet files mounted on EFS was 10x - 12x slower than query that we executed on same folder in our local storage(which is EBS in our case).

We can't move from EFS to EBS since multiple instances needs to access the folder. So we decided to write to folder mounted on EFS, but while reading, read from EBS. T**o achieve this we need a way to sync EFS into our local storage(which is EBS in our case) on multiple instances**

So is there any way to sync EFS to EBS ?

**Note:** In our scenario writes to EFS happens at each 30 minutes, but read can happen at any time

Comment: You could do something like this (on every EC2 server) https://superuser.com/questions/317820/linux-continuously-synchronize-files-one-way

Comment: @MarkB Which approach would be better, running rsync/fpsync as cron job each minute and syncing entire folder vs using pyinotify/inotify to listen to required events. Considering that one minute delay in syncing is not crucial in first approach

Comment: It seems like using inotify to let the filesystem notify you of things would generate less I/O traffic against the EFS volume.

Comment: @MarkB Let's say we are syncing a folder using both rsync and inotify and ine file is changed. Based on file size and date modified rsync will detect which file is changed under the specified folder but it still needs to check metada of all files in folder but in case of inotify no need to check metada for all files instead an event is triggered for only file which have updated right?

Comment: Why don't you test it out and see?

Comment: Have already tried fpsync will give it a try for inotify